# PowerShell get latest string date

Tags: powershell, datetime, datetime-format

I have a list with dates inside

`$date = @('05-28-2020','09-30-2021')`

I want to find the most recent date

I tried to convert string before comparat it :

`[datetime]::ParseExact($date[0],'MM_dd_yyyy', $null)`

But not working

Any ideas ?

Comment: your pattern for the **_exact_** parse does not match your input data. [*grin*] replace the `_` with `-` and things otta works.

Answer (score 1):

- **You can directly cast your date-time strings to [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)** - no need for a `ParseExact()` call - given that your input format is recognized by the [invariant culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) that PowerShell *always* uses in casts.
- [`System.Linq.Enumerable.Max<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Max) allows you to find the maximum in a `[datetime]`-typed enumerable.

Therefore:

```sh
$date = @('05-28-2020','09-30-2021') # Note: The @(...) enclosure isn't strictly needed.

[Linq.Enumerable]::Max([datetime[]] $date)
```

On a US-English system, the above yields `Thursday, September 30, 2021 12:00:00 AM`, i.e. the default output formatting of the most recent date in the input, `[datetime] '09-30-2021'`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- As has been mentioned, the only immediate problem with your `ParseExact()` call was that you used `_` instead of `-`.
- Also note that passing `$null` as the third argument implies that the culture *currently in effect* is used during parsing (as reflected in `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture`; this won't matter with *numeric* formatting sequences such as `MM`, but it would with *symbolic* ones such as `MMM` - and potentially even with unquoted placeholders `:` and `/`.

Answer (score 0):

switch your `_` to `-` and it will work:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = @('05-28-2020','09-30-2021')
$max = '01-01-1999'
$date | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -ge $max){
        $max = $_
    }
}
```

This should do the work.